# AWS Lambda C# asynchronous invoke

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Am I invoking AWS Lambda function asynchronously?

```
private readonly IAmazonLambda amazonLambda;

...

await amazonLambda.InvokeAsync(new Amazon.Lambda.Model.InvokeRequest(){
                InvocationType = InvocationType.Event,
                FunctionName = "my-function"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Am I invoking AWS Lambda function asynchronously?

Yes.

The `await` with an `*Async`-suffixed method suggests the use of the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap).

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Sorry, my question was clearly wrongly placed. I mean if the AWS Lambda function itself is invoked asynchronously: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html

Comment: Ah, that's a different definition of "asynchronous" - essentially meaning "invoke via queue" instead of "invoke directly". So the question is whether this code means "invoke directly with an awaitable API" or "invoke via queue with an awaitable API". I *suspect* the "invoke via queue" behavior is controlled by `InvocationType.Event`, but I'm not familiar enough with the AWS .NET API to say for sure.